# Server Okhttp and Socket.io

Tags: android, socket.io, server, okhttp

my question is this: I am creating a server that listens to Android clients, but I´m already using okhttp to contact the server, what´s the difference between Okhttp and socket.io, meaning what are the functions for each one and on what circumstances should I apply each one?